# CvInvoke.HoughLinesP() not working, any reason why?

Tags: c#, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

I am trying to use HoughLinesP() and Line() and it is not working because it is telling me that listVecs needs to be an IOutputArray. This does not make sense though becuase I need to use a list (or vector). The IOutputArray documentation EVEN SAYS that I can use a "VectorOf{XXX}" AS the output array. I have tried converting listVects by typecasting it to an IOutput Array and that does not work either. I am very frustrated. Here is the tutorial I am using:
 https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html

```
MCvScalar m = new MCvScalar(0, 0, 255);
            List<VectorOfInt> listVecs = new List<VectorOfInt>();
            IOutputArray o;
            CvInvoke.HoughLinesP(source, listVecs, 1, Math.PI / 180, 50, 50, 10);

            for (int i = 0; i < listVecs.Count; i++)
            {
                VectorOfInt v = listVecs[i];
                System.Drawing.Point pointOne = new System.Drawing.Point();
                pointOne.X = (v[0]);
                pointOne.Y = (v[1]);
                System.Drawing.Point pointTwo = new System.Drawing.Point();
                pointTwo.X = (v[2]);
                pointTwo.Y = (v[3]);

                CvInvoke.Line(cdst, pointOne, pointTwo, m, 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LineType.EightConnected, 8);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

HoughlinesP returns Line Segment

try this (note I didn't look at any other code just corrected the variable type and removed unnecessary conversion code)

```
MCvScalar m = new MCvScalar(0, 0, 255);
            listVecs[] = LineSegment2D();
            IOutputArray o;
            listVecs = CvInvoke.HoughLinesP(source, 1, Math.PI / 180, 50, 50, 10);

            for (int i = 0; i < listVecs.Length; i++)
            {


                CvInvoke.Line(cdst, listVecs[i].P1, listVecs[i].P2, m, 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LineType.EightConnected, 8);
            }
```